# Error when installing postgis extension to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Im having problem installing postgis to an existing database.
but getting error like this:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-2.0.so": libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the postgis-2.0.so is in `/usr/local/pgsql/lib/postgis-2.0.so` no problem. the `libgeos_c.so.1` is installed in `/usr/local/lib`.

So, what is the problem here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

BTW, I installed all these followed by this tutorial:

http://www.codingsteps.com/installing-and-configuring-postgresql-in-amazon-linux-ami/

update

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6f55b000)
libgeos-3.3.7.so => /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.3.7.so (0x00007f53700d9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f536fdd0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f536fb4c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f536f7c0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f536f5ab000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f537068d000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've solved this problem, and almost forgot this question i asked before. I found still getting upvote from guys might having this issue.

So basically, I found this issue might be happening because of the `postgis` plugin which i installed by `sudo apt-get install postgis` wasn't properly installed into the position which `PostgreSQl` database preferred. Im really not a linux guy to make sure of this. But seems every time I try installing `postgis` this way, this error will just show up.

**So the cure for this issue is, download, build and install the `postgis` from the source code.**

I followed this [wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21Ubuntu1204src). hope its helpful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

It's *way* easier to just use a sensible Linux distro like Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, RHEL, etc. You can then just use http://apt.postgresql.org/ or http://yum.postgresql.org/ as appropriate and get all this stuff pre-built and easy to install. Amazon's PostgreSQL packaging is [unsafe bordering on incompetent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28245/7788) and should be avoided.

I suspect the immediate problem is `/usr/local/lib` not being on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, so when PostgreSQL `dlopen(...)`'s `postgis-2.0.so` it tries to resolve `libgeos_c.so.1` and fails to find it.

Another possibility would be if `/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1` is a symbolic link to a file that does not exist.

Comment: hey Craig, thanks for your reply. I've just tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` but it not seem to be working. Any idea?

Comment: @Still.Wang Well, just exporting the env var into your shell won't make any difference, since it'd only do anything if you set the environment of the *postgresql server* process. You'd need to modify the init script for postgresql or add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` so it affects every program globally.

Comment: just checked that file and the content was `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib`

Comment: sorry, im really not a linux guy. :(

Comment: OK, so your next step would generally be to run `ldd /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1` . See if there are any errors or missing dependencies. Seriously, though, if you're "not really a Linux guy" you should just *throw this virtual machine away and replace it with a nice sensible Ubuntu or Fedora VM* where there are official PostgreSQL packages including PostGIS, etc. You're doing it the hard way.

Comment: If running `ldconfig` has no effect, I'd be at the point of hooking `strace` up to the `postgres` backend to see what exactly the dynamic linker is doing, or enabling `LD_DEBUG`. You don't want to go there if you're new to Linux. This is a good time to be re-examining your use of Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 5):

If you installed the postgis by source, maybe you forgot to run `sudo ldconfig`. Running this worked for me!

Thank you Yunwei.W, i saw this in the wiki you shared!

Comment: this saved the day for me

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have faced similar problem accidentally. On Cent OS 6 I installed binary PostgreSQL 9.3 from PostgreSQL YUM repository. Compiled GDAL library version 1.11.0 from official stable tar. Then compiled PostGIS 2.1.4dev from original PostGIS repository. Unit tests showed, that `libgdal` was not loaded because it was not found. Error message looked similar to one in the original question. @Craig gave idea of using `strace`. The point is in attaching `strace` specifically to the process that was created just after the connection of client to DBMS. After you attach `strace` to DBMS, make client ask server to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` on current database and see the output of `strace`. In my case it gave this:

```
open("/lib64/tls/x86_64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffefb20290) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/tls/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/lib64/x86_64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fffefb20290)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffefb20290) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fffefb20290) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libgdal.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
```

It shows which specific paths DBMS tries to find library in. In my situation library lies in `/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1.18.0` with symbolic links for broader version use in same directory. My solution was to put symbolic links to these files into `/usr/lib64` directory.

Comment: Can you tell me as to what you did to copy over all the symlinks to the directory also you just seem to be having all the synlinks in /lib64 in my case its in different directories what do you propose for that. I am kinda stuck at this process.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` should contain paths for postgresql libs dir and geos libs.

Example for postgresql 9.6.6 on Amazon linux:

```sh
-create postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf with "/usr/lib64/pgsql96/" path
-create libgeos.conf with "/usr/local/lib/" path 
-check the geos library present in 
 ldconfig -v | grep geos
- if yes compile the extension
sudo -u postgres -- psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so.1 /usr/lib/`

which basically symlinks to the location django wants it to be. By default, the `libgeos_c.so.1` is installed in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder

Answer (score 0):

if it helps anyone in the future, I had a similar problem (with postgis 3.0.1 now), and it turned out the root of the problem was that on AWS Linux 2, I had to manually install the `pgxs` part of postgres (to manage Extensions), and during that installation part of the `./configure` command hard-coded a path for the extension libraries to `/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/` (where `libperl.so` lives).  Here was the configure command:

(see the very last parameters)

```
/usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/Makefile.global:configure_args =  '--build=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-rpath' '--with-perl' '--with-tcl' '--with-tclconfig=/usr/lib64' '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-pam' '--with-gssapi' '--with-ossp-uuid' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--enable-nls' '--enable-dtrace' '--with-selinux' '--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' '--datadir=/usr/share/pgsql' '--with-systemd' '--with-icu' '--with-python' 'build_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/ -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro ' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'

/usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/Makefile.global:CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/ -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/
```

Anyway, I eventually figured out through @progalgo 's mention of `strace` that the libraries that postgis was trying to use (when creating the extension) were housed in `/usr/local/lib` but no amount of configuring the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable would make it look there.  So I moved the file from the perl folder over to /usr/local/lib, removed that /CORE directory, and symlinked "CORE" over to /usr/local/lib itself.  A bit hack-y, but it worked.